# On the declensions of the pronoun "man"? Part I: Finding a substitute for the genitive for "man"

Tags: pronoun, genitive, declension, personal-pronoun

## Part I

In [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/man#Indefinitpronomen) reads:

> Das Indefinitpronomen des Nominativ Singular *man* hat keine weiteren Formen; bei der Verwendung in anderen Fällen muss daher auf die Formen des Indefinitpronomens *einer*, namentlich *einem* im Dativ beziehungsweise *einen* im Akkusativ zurückgegriffen werden.

If I understand correctly, the non-nominative cases mentioned there are used as follows:

**Accusative**

> Wenn ein Polizist **einen** so fest anschaut, fühlt man sich unvermeidlich ganz kommisch.

**Dative**

> Wenn die Ehefrau **einem** einen Wagen schenkt, ist [...]

(another question on the dative of *man* is [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11502/on-the-declensions-of-the-pronoun-man-part-ii-does-the-dative-depends-on-the)).

A strightforward generalization of the prescription above would lead to suspect that one could choose *eines* for the substitute of the genitive for *man*. So, would the following sentece be correct?

> Wenn **eines** Wagen kaputt ist, muss man den Wagen reparieren (lassen).

(Here I mean *eines* might be the equivalent of *one's* in English.) And if so, how does it sound, stylistically speaking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Frage ist schon falsch gestellt. Du zitierst die völlig richtige Aussage aus Wiktionary, in der festgestellt wird, dass »man« keine weiteren Formen hat, und fragst trotzdem nach dem Genitiv von »man«.

Die einzig richtige Antwort lautet daher:

`Es gibt keinen Genitiv von »man«!`

---

Ich stelle aber die Richtigkeit der anderen Aussage aus deinem Wiktionary-Zitat in Frage: Man muss nicht zwingend »man« durch eine Form von »einer« ersetzen. Das *kann* man machen, aber man *muss* es nicht. Im Fall des Genitivs ist »einer« sogar die falsche Wahl.

Folgende Sätze sind ebenfalls völlig korrekt und drücken inhaltlich dasselbe aus wie deine beiden Beispielsätze:

> Wenn ein Polizist **jemanden** so fest anschaut, fühlt man sich unvermeidlich ganz komisch.
>   Wenn die Ehefrau **jemandem** einen Wagen schenkt, ist […]

Dein Genitiv-Beispiel würde man also auch so formulieren können:

> Wenn **jemandes** Wagen kaputt ist, muss man den Wagen reparieren (lassen).

Dein Beispiel mit »eines« anstelle von »jemandes« ist unüblich und wird daher von Muttersprachlern als falsch empfunden. Ich kann aber nicht sagen, ob deine Variante auch nach objektiven Kriterien tatsächlich falsch ist.

Im letzten Beispiel ist es irrelevant, dass der Wagen einen Halter/Besitzer/Eigentümer hat. Daher kann man das Objekt unserer Diskussion auch ganz einfach weglassen und durch einen unbestimmten Artikel ersetzen, ohne den Sinn des Satzes zu verändern:

> Wenn **ein** Wagen kaputt ist, muss man den Wagen reparieren (lassen).

Dann drängt sich auch folgende Vereinfachung auf, die auch bei Verwendung von »eines« oder »jemandes« angebracht wäre:

> Wenn ein Wagen kaputt ist, muss man **ihn** reparieren (lassen).

---

Du kannst auch in jedem beliebigen Satz, in dem »man« vorkommt, stattdessen das Wort »jemand« verwenden. Allerdings findet dabei eine Verschiebung der Bedeutung statt. Das Wort »man« schließt den Sprecher immer ziemlich deutlich ein:

> Man tut, was man kann.

Wird verstanden als:

> Ich tue, was ich kann.

Die Wörter »einer« und »jemand« grenzen den Sprecher aber aus. Dieser Effekt ist bei »jemand« stärker als bei »einer«. »Jemand« hat dafür den Vorteil, dass das Geschlecht der bezeichneten Person offengelassen werden kann:

> Einer tut, was einer kann.
>   Eine tut, was eine kann.
>   Jemand tut, was jemand kann.

Abschließend kann man sagen, dass »einer« und »jemand« nicht genau dasselbe ausdrücken wie »man«. Das Wort »man« kann aber nicht dekliniert werden, daher muss es immer dann, wenn ein anderer Fall zu verwenden ist, durch etwas anderes ersetzt werden. Als Ersatz kommen vor allem »einer« und »jemand« in Frage, aber auch andere Umschreibungen (die häufig einen ganz anderen Satzbau erfordern und hier nicht diskutiert wurden) sind möglich und üblich.

Eine Gemeinsamkeit aller Ersatz-Formulierungen ist aber, dass keine davon exakt dasselbe ausdrückt wie »man«. Eine Formulierung, die in allen Situationen optimal ist, gibt es nicht.

Comment: Das "jemandes" kannst Du nicht später mit "man" wiederaufnehmen, es muss dann "er" (oder gegebenenfalls "sie") heißen.

Comment: @c.p.: 1. Wiktionary ist nicht Wikipedia. 2. Das Wort »man« ist ein Indefinitpronomen (unbestimmtes Fürwort) das nur in der dritten Person Einzahl und nur im Nominativ vorkommt. Es hat kein grammatikalisches Geschlecht (Genus) und kann auch nicht nach dem Geschlecht dekliniert werden. Genau das ist mit »hat keine weiteren Formen« gemeint. Und die Tatsache, dass es ein Fehler ist zu glauben es gäbe trotzdem Formen von »man« in anderen Fällen, habe ich ganz zu Beginn meiner Antwort thematisiert.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Auf wen soll sich den das »er« im Satz »Wenn jemandes Wagen kaputt ist, muss *er* den Wagen reparieren (lassen)« beziehen? An dieser Stelle ist »man« schon richtig. Der Wagen muss schließlich ja auch gar nicht von der Person repariert werden (oder zur Reparatur gebracht werden) der der Wagen gehört.

Answer (score 1):

As  a substitute for the genitive one uses "von jemand" in der gesprochenen Sprache. "eines" wird nicht 
verwendet.
Es gibt auch die Form "jemandes/jemands". Mir liegt sie nicht.

Comment: Wobei allerdings ambig bleibt, ob der jemand, dessen Wagen kaputt ist, und "man", der ihn reparieren lassen muss, derselbe Mensch sind oder nicht. Im Ernstfall versuchen wir also meistens, eine ganz andere Formulierung zu finden, oder weichen in die zweite Person aus: "Wenn Dein Wagen kaputt ist, musst Du ihn reparieren lassen."

Comment: @elena  "dein wagen" ist gut. Oder: wenn einem der wagen kaputt gegangen ist...". - Was ist "ambig?

Comment: ambig: ambivalent, zweideutig, mehrdeutig – English: ambiguous; kein sehr geläufiges Wort im Deutschen ;)

Comment: Ich  dachte mirs, noch nie gehört. Vielleicht in anderen Gegenden gebräuchlich oder ich bin zu alt und kriege nicht mehr alle Veränderungen der Sprache mit.

Comment: *Jemands* kenne ich auch nicht, *[jemandes](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/jemandes)* hingegen schon, wobei auch dieses nicht sehr gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: In gesprochener Sprache kann unbetontes e ausfallen. Ich glaube, es wäre interessant, zusammenzustellen, was es alles für Möglickeiten als Ersatz für den Genitiv von "man" und "jemand" gibt.