# On the declensions of the pronoun "man". Part II: does the dative depend on the gender of the speaker?

Tags: pronoun, dative, declension

## Part II

([Part I of this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/on-the-declensions-of-the-pronoun-man-part-i-whats-its-genitive-form) verses on the genitive for *man*)

In [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/man#Indefinitpronomen) reads:

> Das Indefinitpronomen des Nominativ Singular *man* hat keine weiteren Formen; bei der Verwendung in anderen Fällen muss daher auf die Formen des Indefinitpronomens *einer*, namentlich *einem* im Dativ beziehungsweise *einen* im Akkusativ zurückgegriffen werden.

Does the dative for *man* depend on the gender of who is speaking? I think this question is better explained by example:

*Context*: A woman, who recently gave birth, tells her friends:

> Wenn der Arzt {einer · einem} das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, fühlt man sich unendlich glücklich.

Which is the right declension there? (I'd go with *einer* but I need confirmation)

Comment: Actually, you would use both "einer" and "einem": "Wenn einer(=e.g. doc) einem(=me) das Neugeborene zeigt". Or also possible "Wenn man(=e.g. me) einem(=someone else) das Neugeborene zeigt".

Comment: Did you mean "zeigt" or "gezeigt wird"?

Comment: @c.p.: Your example sentence is missing a subject. Both Em1's and Carsten's suggestions can fix that.

Comment: If a woman opts for the impersonal "man" to tell her friends about such an extraordinary and very individual sensation, then there are more important problems to solve than grammar. This phrase should read "Als der Arzt **mir** ..., fühlte **ich mich**...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, one would use "einem".

> Wenn der Arzt einem das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, fühlt man sich unendlich glücklich.

---

I suppose people who are unhappy with the idea of "[generisches Maskulinum](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generisches_Maskulinum)" might say "einer", thus marking the word for gender. In the same vein, some people say "frau" instead of "man":

> Frau tut, was frau kann.

instead of

> Man tut, was man kann.

Comment: The question has just been updated. Do you mind addressing the change, too?!

Comment: @Em1 I changed the question so that the answer matches it. No need to change this answer now.

Comment: @c.p. Well, now that you added "der Arzt" to the beginning of the sentence, this answer addresses your question again. However, without the noun, i.e. your second version of the question, you only need "einem": Wenn einem das Neugeborene gezeigt wird. Just to clarify for potential future visitors (I'm aware that you now that): This is passive and the other person (the doc here) is not mentioned explicitly. In active voice, as the question stands now you (and originally was) you need subject and dative object.

Comment: Sowas geschieht frauchmal unter dem Deckfrautel fraugelhaften Efrauzipationsverständnisses.

Answer (score 4):

Richtig ist nur diese Variante:

> Wenn der Arzt **einem** das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, fühlt man sich unendlich glücklich.

Die Verwendung von »man« oder »einem« zeigt an, dass offengelassen wird, wem das Baby gezeigt wird. Aus dem Satz kann man nicht herauslesen, dass das Baby der Mutter gezeigt wird. Das Baby könnte auch dem Vater, dem Hauselektriker oder der Putzfrau gezeigt werden. Aber jeder, der das Baby zu Gesicht bekommt, fühlt sich unendlich glücklich.

Weil das biologische Geschlecht der Person, der das Baby gezeigt wird, unklar ist, wird automatisch die grammatikalisch männliche Form gewählt. (Diese Regel ist gegenwärtig Gegenstand einer teilweise sehr emotional geführten Diskussion rund um die Gleichberechtigung der Geschlechter.)

### Edit:

Falls klar ist, wem das Baby gezeigt wird, muss man ja sich ja nicht mit Begriffen wie »man«, »jemand« oder »einer« herumärgern:

> Wenn der Arzt **der Mutter** das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, fühlt **sie** sich unendlich glücklich.

Wenn das nicht nur für eine bestimmte Mutter gilt, sondern für jede beliebige, dann:

> Wenn der Arzt ***einer* Mutter** das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, fühlt **sie** sich unendlich glücklich.

Oder aus der Perspektive der Mutter:

> Wenn der Arzt **mir** das Neugeborene zum ersten Mal zeigt, *fühle **ich** mich* unendlich glücklich.

Comment: Was passiert dann, wenn das Geschlecht der Person, der das Baby gezeigt wird, klar ist? Wenn wir wissen, dass diese Person eine Frau ist, würde man dann "Wenn der Arzt einer das Neugeborene zeigt" sagen?

Comment: Ja, Entschuldigung, aber wie in der Frage lautet, ist eine Frau, die Person, die „Wenn der Artz einer das Neugeborene zum 1. Mal zeigt“ sagt. Das finde ich wichtig. Ein zweites Beispiel wäre mit anderer Tätigkeit, die nur Frauen können: „Nach der Geburt gibt der Chef einer/einem *X* Tagen frei, um sich zu erholen und die Mutterschaft zu genießen.“ Ich gehe davon aus, dass man schon auf Frauen beschränkt ist.

Comment: @karoshi Eben, das war die Frage :) Deswegen habe ich geschrieben *"Context: A* **woman**, *who recently gave birth, tells her friends"*. Das deutet darauf hin, dass es nach "weiblicher Erfahrung" klingt.

Comment: Es stimmt zwar in soweit, dass der Satz selbst offen lässt, wem das Baby gezeigt wird, aber: In 99% der Fälle ist hier eindeutig ein Elternteil gemeint und der Kontext klärt diese ungeklärte Frage immer auf. Daher weiß man in aller Regel immer, wenn es sich um eine Frau handelt. Und trotzdem würde man dann "man" bzw. "einem" verwenden. "Man" bzw. "einem" steht aber synonym zu "Leute" oder zu einer nicht näher beschriebenen Person. Die Aussage trifft nämlich immer zu, egal wer letztlich wirklich durch "man" referiert wird. Es ist eben eine Verallgemeinerung.

Comment: Danke für die Kommentare. Ich habe meiner Antwort noch einen Abschnitt hinzugefügt.