# Dativ von "man"?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative

> (a) Man kann das Kino wählen, das man gefällt.

Ist dieser Satz in Ordnung? Oder muss man den Satz ohne "man" umschreiben, wie:

> (b) Jeder kann das Kino wählen, das ihm gefällt.

Obwohl die Bedeutungen von den beiden Sätzen ähnlich sind, sind sie nicht genau dieselbe. Eine Übersetzung ins Englische macht das klar.

> One can choose the cinema that one likes.
>
> Everyone can choose the cinema that he likes.

Comment: Related: [On the declensions of the pronoun “man”? Part I: Finding a substitute for the genitive for “man”](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11501/on-the-declensions-of-the-pronoun-man-part-i-finding-a-substitute-for-the-ge)

Comment: Related: [On the declensions of the pronoun “man”. Part II: does the dative depend on the gender of the speaker?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/11502/on-the-declensions-of-the-pronoun-man-part-ii-does-the-dative-depend-on-the)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Das Indefinitpronomen „man“ hat nur eine einzige Form (Nominativ Singular) und kommt ausschließlich in der Funktion des Subjekts vor.

Laut *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* verwendet man „einen“ als Akkusativ und „einem“ als Dativ:

> Dort kann man kommen und gehen, wie es einem beliebt.
>
> Diese Musik lässt einen nicht mehr los.

Answer (score 7):

The first sentence is devinitively wrong:

> (a) Man kann das Kino wählen, das **einem** gefällt.

The second sentence is usual and a bit colloquial, you can also write:

> (c) Jeder kann das Kino wählen, welches ihm gefällt.