# "es wird so entschieden, wie einem in der ersten Wut das Urteil aus dem Munde fährt"

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronoun

This post is on *es* and *einem* as highlighted in this passage from chapter '[Der Fall Robinson](https://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/amerika-9768/23)' of Amerika (Der Verschollene) by Frankz Kafka.

> Karl sah ein, daß er eigentlich seinen Posten schon verloren hatte, denn der Oberkellner hatte es bereits ausgesprochen, der Oberportier als fertige Tatsache wiederholt, und wegen eines Liftjungen dürfte wohl die Bestätigung der Entlassung seitens der Hoteldirektion nicht nötig sein. Es war allerdings schneller gegangen, als er gedacht hatte, denn schließlich hatte er doch zwei Monate gedient, so gut er konnte, und gewiß besser als mancher andere Junge. Aber auf solche Dinge wird eben im entscheidenden Augenblick offenbar in keinem Weltteil, weder in Europa, noch in Amerika, Rücksicht genommen, sondern **es** wird so entschieden, wie **einem** in der ersten Wut das Urteil aus dem Munde fährt. Vielleicht wäre es jetzt am besten gewesen, wenn er sich gleich verabschiedet hätte und weggegangen wäre, die Oberköchin und Therese schliefen vielleicht noch, er hätte sich, um ihnen die Enttäuschung und Trauer über sein Benehmen wenigstens beim persönlichen Abschied zu ersparen, brieflich verabschieden, hätte rasch seinen Koffer packen und in der Stille fortgehen können.

**QUESTION**

1. Is *es* a reference to some foregoing abstract item such as the fact *daß er eigentlich seinen Posten schon verloren hatte*? Or is it an expletive sitting in to mark the first position?
2. Is *einem* being used like *one* in English (or *man* in German) to refer to an indefinite person?  On this guess, the clause would mean something like:

   > but it is so decided as in the first anger the judgment goes from the mouth to one (i.e. the person affected, here Karl).
3. If the guess in 2 is correct, can we replace *einem* with *man*?  If so, what is the dative form of *man*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## *es*

The easiest way to test whether *es* is a *Platzhalter* is to check whether it disappears when something else is put in first position (which unfortunately only helps native speakers). In this case, it is.

> [...] sondern **dann** wird so entschieden, wie [...]

*Entscheiden* in principle allows an object. In the quoted example, the object is omitted because the text talks about the manner in which things in general are decided. There is no plausible antecedent for *es*. The following example is different; here, *es* refers to *das Ganze* (which in turn refers to some legal conundrum).

> Ich habe keine Ahnung, wo **das** endet. Letztlich wird **das** irgendwann vor Gerichten entschieden. Tatsache ist: Es scheint, jedenfalls nach der Prüfung, keine höchstrichterliche Entscheidung dazu zu geben. **Das Ganze** endet [...] vor dem Europäischen Gerichtshof oder von mir aus auch beim EGMR. Aber da wird **es** dann entschieden. ([source](https://www.landtag.nrw.de/portal/WWW/dokumentenarchiv/Dokument/MMA16-819.pdf))

## *man*

*Man* is nominative only. When another case is required, forms of *ein-* can be used.

> Zuerst bekommt **man** Fieber und es wird **einem** schlecht. ([source](https://books.google.de/books?id=4_QUAwAAQBAJ&q=%22wird+einem+schlecht%22#v=snippet&q=%22wird%20einem%20schlecht%22&f=false))
>
> Schon von der Ferne war der Angriff auf Stuttgart so entsetzlich, dass es **einen** graut bei dem Gedanken, noch einmal in diese Mühle hineinzusollen. ([source](https://books.google.de/books?id=N_l3DwAAQBAJ&q=einen+graut#v=snippet&q=%22einen%20graut%22&f=false))

Your translation of the passage seems to indicate that you misunderstood it.

> wie **einem** das Urteil aus dem Munde fährt
> as the verdict slips from **one's** mouth

This has been called *dativus possessivus* or [*Pertinenzdativ*](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/1148). Compare:

> Wasch **dir** die Hände! =Wasch **deine** Hände!

I felt reminded of this saying, which in its general form has *einem* as *dativus possessivus*.

> reden, wie einem der Schnabel gewachsen ist
> talk as one pleases (*lit.* talk as one's beak is grown)

Answer (score 3):

> Aber auf solche Dinge wird eben [im entscheidenden Augenblick offenbar]
>   in keinem Weltteil, weder in Europa, noch in Amerika, Rücksicht
>   genommen, sondern es wird so entschieden, wie einem in der ersten Wut
>   das Urteil aus dem Munde fährt.

[] left out the part about the timing because that would muddle the sentence even more

> But to such things, not in any part of the world, neither in Europe ,
>   nor in America, any consideration is given, rather **it** is being
>   decided as the judgements slips from **one's** lips in the first
>   anger.

I do not really understand your first two questions, but maybe this rough translation (grammar bent to better fit the original (which has an outdated sentence structure to boot)) helps ?

About 3): .... sondern es wird so entschieden wie **man** in der ersten Wut das Urteil aus dem Munde fahren **lässt**. --- 'man' needs to be active here, nothing happens to 'man'; things happen to ''einem'; In the original sentence the judgement ('Urteil') does 'aus ... fahren' ('slip from/out'), so the judgement is the subject, the mouth (and the attached person) the object. To use 'man', the mouth needs to do something to the judgement (**let** slip, spit it out etc).

Comment: Then my interpretation of *einem* as *to one (i.e. the person affected, here Karl)* is wrong? That would have to be *zu einem*?

Comment: @Catomic In this sentence, _einem_ refers to the person that judges, not to the affected person.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes (es = the decision making situation)
2. yes
3. no (would change the case)

As far as I understand this text it is quite "abstract" / "metaphorical". The writer speaks in the third (unspecific) person / the people as kind of external decider.

For the text flow you cannot use *man* here, because that would require to rewrite the whole sentence:

As [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/dativ-von-man) enlightened me: *einem* is dativ of *man*: the rewrite would require to change the case.

Answer (score 1):

1. I read *es* as an expletive, as you suggest.
2. Indeed, *einem* is used as *one* in English.
3. Well, the [dative form of *man*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/dativ-von-man) is: *einem*. Or, if you prefer to put it this way, since *man* does not have forms in cases which are not nominative, you have to use forms or *einer* instead.